# BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromPath images not showing on map

Tags: android, mobile

I am trying to put my markers on google map. But although I debug(everythings looking fine), my markers not showing on map. Can you help me what is the problem?

```
                                             String imageInSD = Config.APP_IMAGES_URL + sh.cover_image_file;[enter image description here][1]



                                                                customMarker = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                                                                        .position(markerLatLng)
                                                                        .title(sh.name)
                                                                        .snippet(sh.description.substring(0, Math.min(sh.description.length(), 80)) + "...")
                                                                        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromPath(imageInSD)) // in debug looking www.asd.com/abc.jpg(right paths)
                                                                        .anchor(0.5f, 1));
```

I tried also this

.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.FromFile(imageInSD))

but not working? Where is problem
Looking right path in debug. Added screenshot. But in application map is null

Comment: Where *exactly* is `imageInSD` pointing? Your comment is not a complete filesystem path.

Comment: I couldn't get it sorry. What did you mean?

it is image path. 

I have a "for" loop. Everytime marker have to get another image. When I debug I controlled imageInSD everytime get TRUE path. But in application it is not working. Null map showing.

for exm
1.loop -->imageInSD = www.abc.com/1.jpeg
2.loop -->imageInSD = www.abc.com/2.jpeg
...

in here BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromPath(imageInSD) not work i think

Answer (score 0):

`www.abc.com/1.jpeg` is not a valid filesystem path. It looks like an HTTP URL that is missing its scheme.

`fromPath()` takes a filesystem path. Given a `File` object pointing to your image, use `getAbsolutePath()` to convert it into a `String` representation of a filesystem path, and pass that value to `fromPath()`.

If your `imageInSD` values are actually URLs, you will need to download those images first. `BitmapDescriptorFactory` will not download those for you. And most image-loading libraries are aimed at things like `ImageView`, so most of those will not help you. You can see if somebody has a recipe for using a library like Picasso to populate a marker. Otherwise, use `HttpURLConnection`, OkHttp, etc. to download the image, before adding the marker.

Comment: Actually I can tell wrong. Yes, I need to get http url from my server for every image. But in .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromPath(imageInSD)) I couldnt. 

Can you help more how can I solve. Thanks

Comment: @user3404273: "I need to get http url from my server for every image" -- you will need to download those images yourself. See the updated answer.

Comment: Thanks but do you have code sample? I am not proffesional so much. Depends your words, I need to some help to get data.

Comment: @user3404273: I do not have any examples of using `BitmapDescriptorFactory` with images from the Internet, sorry.

Comment: I tried     URL url = new URL(Config.APP_IMAGES_URL + sh.cover_image_file);
                                                                    Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream());    ---    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(bmp)) 
                                                                        Not working again

Comment: @user3404273: You cannot perform network I/O on the main application thread. You should be crashing somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of a class that can be used to download from a website and convert to something that gmaps APIs can display.  I lifted this from a project I am working on and pulled out the not applicable stuff - did not try to compile it, but it should be close.

```
class DownloadWebpageAsynch  extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Integer>
{
    private String fileName;
    private final String TAG = "DownloadWebpageAsynch";

    // onPostExecute displays the results of the AsyncTask.
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Integer result)
    {
        // Perforrm any work here on the UI thread
    // in your case, create the bitmap for the google map

    BitmapDescriptor bd = BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromPath(fileName);

    // use bd in google map calls as the bitmap to add to the map
    }

    protected void DownloadComplete(BufferedInputStream inStream)
    {
    // Perform work here upon download complete on the background thread
        // inStream is what was returned by the web server

    // Safe file to temp storage
    try
    {
        File tempFile = File.createTempFile("1", ".jpg");
        tempFile.deleteOnExit();
        fileName = tempFile.toString();
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(tempFile);
        byte[] readyBytes = new byte[1000];
        int numRead = inStream.read(readyBytes, 0, 999);
        while(numRead != -1)
        {
        fos.write(readyBytes, 0, numRead);
        numRead = inStream.read(readyBytes, 0, 999);
        }
        fos.close();
    } catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }



    @Override
    protected Integer doInBackground(String... urls)
    {
        // params comes from the execute() call: params[0] is the url.
        try
        {
        downloadUrl(urls[0]);
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            Log.d(TAG, "Failed with exception " + e.toString());
        }
        return 0;
    }

    // Given a URL, establishes an HttpUrlConnection and retrieves
    // the web page content as a InputStream, which it returns as
    // a string.
    private void downloadUrl(String myurl) throws IOException
    {
        BufferedInputStream is = null;
        downloadFailed = false;

        try
        {
            URL url = new URL(myurl);
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setReadTimeout(10000); // 10 second timeout
            conn.setConnectTimeout(10000); // 10 second timeout
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            // Starts the query
            conn.connect();
            responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
            if(responseCode != 200)
            {
                Log.d(TAG, "Download Failed");
            }
            else
            {
          DownloadComplete(new BufferedInputStream(conn.getInputStream());
            }
            conn.disconnect();
        }
        catch (SocketTimeoutException e)
        {
      Log.d(TAG, "Failed with exception " + e.toString());
        }
        finally
        {
            if (is != null)
            {
                is.close();
            }
        }
    }// private String downloadUrl(String myurl) throws IOException
```

Hope this helps.